# Is it possible to add session data to ASPStateTempSessions manually? We want to write a session variable from a Node app

Tags: node.js, .net, session

We're building a Vue.js application and want to create a session variable that .Net application can use later. Is it possible to create a session variable "manually" using T-SQL?

Comment: What are you really trying to do, and where does Node.js fit into this? If your front-end is Vue and your back-end is .NET, perhaps the back-end should create the session itself?

Comment: What we'd REALLY like to do is wire up SharePoint 2019 to authenticate via our IdP but we can't seem to find a way to configure that. So, we thought that we'd have our Vue.js portal application authenticate via our IdP and then create a .Net session variable with the information received from the SAML assertion so that when/if the user went to our SharePoint site it could read that session information. I know, very clunky, but we're pulling our hair out trying to figure out how to keep users from having to authenticate again in SharePoint....

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but this says you should be able to tell SharePoint to use a SAML IdP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/implement-saml-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-server